# enable the data access for the current server - is this operation logged somewhere?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, security, linked-server, dynamic-sql

I have a similar question related to the same subject:

[security concerns over enabling data access for the current server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/130716/22336)

```
BEGIN TRY
    PRINT  @@SERVERNAME
    PRINT  DB_NAME()
    PRINT 'enable the data access for the current server'
    EXEC sp_serveroption @server = @@servername
                        ,@optname =  'data access'     
                        ,@optvalue =  'TRUE'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT '--EXCEPTION WAS CAUGHT--' + CHAR(13) +
              'THE ERROR NUMBER:' + COALESCE(CAST ( ERROR_NUMBER()  AS VARCHAR), 'NO INFO') + CHAR(13) 

        PRINT 'SEVERITY: '        + COALESCE(CAST ( ERROR_SEVERITY()  AS VARCHAR), 'NO INFO') + CHAR(13) +
              'STATE: '           + COALESCE(CAST ( ERROR_STATE() AS VARCHAR), 'NO INFO')  + CHAR(13) 

        PRINT 'PROCEDURE: '       + COALESCE(CAST ( COALESCE(ERROR_PROCEDURE(),'NO INFO')  AS VARCHAR), 'NO INFO') + CHAR(13) +
              'LINE NUMBER: '     + COALESCE(CAST ( ERROR_LINE() AS VARCHAR), 'NO INFO')  + CHAR(13) 

        PRINT 'ERROR MESSAGE: '
        PRINT  CAST ( COALESCE(ERROR_MESSAGE(),'NO INFO')   AS NTEXT)

END CATCH
GO
```

Before anyone says anything about my `NTEXT` above, I would like to say I am not using this anymore I [use this procedure from Solomon Rutzky (with thanks) instead](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/205730/22336).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, calls to `sp_serveroption` are not logged to the default trace, the system_health XE session, or the SQL Server error log. If you want to audit these, you may be able to do it with a server-level audit. Or don't give everyone permissions to do it...